# Center image inside div horizontally

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to set the image with arrow up/down to horizontally center of the div.

[image]

I have read some tutorials and questions here, but the following method does not work:

```
.img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Its made with Bootstrap, so integrated the part in snippet below for you to see. It also has some functions  with JS which makes the animation and change the image when it's clicked.

```js
/* Animation */
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.text').hide();
  $('.expander').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
  });
  $('.text').slideUp(200);
});

/* Change image */
$(function() {
  $('.expander').click(function(){
    $(this).children('img').each(function(){
      $(this).toggle(0);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.red { 
  background-color: #cc1042;
}
.whitetext {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.lefttext { 
  text-align: left; 
}
.centertext { 
  text-align: center;
}
.righttext {
  text-align: right;
}
.littpadding { 
  padding: 15px;
}
.paddingned80 {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.close { 
  opacity: 1!important;
}
.close:focus, .close:hover {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
.clickexpander {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.clickexpander img {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 luft whitetext centertext whitelink">
  <div class="littpadding paddingned80 red">
    <h2>Sesong</h2>
    <h3>990,- pr år</h3>
    <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
      <div class="expander clickexpander">
        <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
        <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
      </div>
    </a>

    <div style="display:none;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 littluft lefttext luftopp">
          <p>
            Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 2 ganger årlig
          </p>    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center using `transform` - one of the ways you can center a positioned element. Add these styles to `clickexpander`:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

See demo below:

```js
/* Animation */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.text').hide();
  $('.expander').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
  });
  $('.text').slideUp(200);
});

/* Change image */
$(function() {
  $('.expander').click(function() {
    $(this).children('img').each(function() {
      $(this).toggle(0);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: #cc1042;
}
.whitetext {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.lefttext {
  text-align: left;
}
.centertext {
  text-align: center;
}
.righttext {
  text-align: right;
}
.littpadding {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
.paddingned80 {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.close {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
.close:focus,
.close:hover {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
.clickexpander {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.clickexpander img {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 luft whitetext centertext whitelink">
  <div class="littpadding paddingned80 red">
    <h2>Sesong</h2>
    <h3>990,- pr år</h3>
    <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
      <div class="expander clickexpander">
        <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
        <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
      </div>
    </a>

    <div style="display:none;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 littluft lefttext luftopp">
          <p>
            Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 2 ganger årlig
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solves the problem. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:center` to `.clickexpander` and `display:inline-block` to `img` and make sure to add `position:relative` the parent div when you used `position:absolute`

```js
/* Animation */
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.text').hide();
  $('.expander').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
  });
  $('.text').slideUp(200);
});

/* Change image */
$(function() {
  $('.expander').click(function(){
    $(this).children('img').each(function(){
      $(this).toggle(0);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.red { background-color: #cc1042; }
.whitetext { color: #ffffff; }
.lefttext { text-align: left; }
.centertext { text-align: center; }
.righttext { text-align: right; }

.littpadding {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.paddingned80 { 
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  position:relative;
}

.close { 
  opacity: 1!important;
  display:inline-block;
  float:none !important;
}

.close:focus, .close:hover {
  opacity: 1!important;
}

.clickexpander {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10px; 
  text-align: center;
  width: 95%;
}

.clickexpander img {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 luft whitetext centertext whitelink">
  <div class="littpadding paddingned80 red">
    <h2>Sesong</h2>
    <h3>990,- pr år</h3>
    <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
      <div class="expander clickexpander">
        <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: inline-block;">
        <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
      </div>
    </a>

    <div style="display:none;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 littluft lefttext luftopp">
          <p>
            Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 2 ganger årlig
          </p>    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
.expander, .littpadding a{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.expander img{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

```js
/* Animation */
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.text').hide();
  $('.expander').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
  });
  $('.text').slideUp(200);
});

/* Change image */
$(function() {
  $('.expander').click(function(){
    $(this).children('img').each(function(){
      $(this).toggle(0);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.red { background-color: #cc1042; }
.whitetext { color: #ffffff; }
.lefttext { text-align: left; }
.centertext { text-align: center; }
.righttext { text-align: right; }

.littpadding {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.paddingned80 { 
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  position:relative;
}

.close { 
  opacity: 1!important;
}

.close:focus, .close:hover {
  opacity: 1!important;
}

.clickexpander {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10px; 
  text-align: center;
  width: 95%;
}

.clickexpander img {
  max-width: 50px;
}


.expander, .littpadding a{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.expander img{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 luft whitetext centertext whitelink">
  <div class="littpadding paddingned80 red">
    <h2>Sesong</h2>
    <h3>990,- pr år</h3>
    <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
      <div class="expander clickexpander">
        <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: inline-block;">
        <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
      </div>
    </a>

    <div style="display:none;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 littluft lefttext luftopp">
          <p>
            Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 2 ganger årlig
          </p>    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
just add .expander {left:50%;} to your css
```

```js
/* Animation */
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.text').hide();
  $('.expander').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
  });
  $('.text').slideUp(200);
});

/* Change image */
$(function() {
  $('.expander').click(function(){
    $(this).children('img').each(function(){
      $(this).toggle(0);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.red { 
  background-color: #cc1042;
}
.expander {
left:50%;
}
.lefttext  p {
text-align:center;
}
.whitetext {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.lefttext{ 
  text-align: left; 
}
.centertext { 
  text-align: center;
}
.righttext {
  text-align: right;
}
.littpadding { 
  padding: 15px;
}
.paddingned80 {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.close { 
  opacity: 1!important;
}
.close:focus, .close:hover {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
.clickexpander {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.clickexpander img {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 luft whitetext centertext whitelink">
  <div class="littpadding paddingned80 red">
    <h2>Sesong</h2>
    <h3>990,- pr år</h3>
    <a href="#/" title="Prisliste" data-target="#">
      <div class="expander clickexpander">
        <img class="open" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilned.png" alt="Open" style="display: block;">
        <img class="close" src="http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pilopp.png" alt="Close" style="display: none;">
      </div>
    </a>

    <div style="display:none;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 littluft lefttext luftopp">
          <p>
            Befaring av hytte/fritidshus og befaringsrapport 2 ganger årlig
          </p>    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```